# Chrome works great, but my div "tables" in Firefox and IE extend past the page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Here is a [link to the site.](http://pegasuslaw.org/knowurrights/)

In Chrome, I see the infographic as a nice page all the way down.
In IE or Firefox, the "Sexual Health Care", "Mental Health Care", and "FYI" sections all extend past the right side of the page.

Here is the faulty code snippet for "Mental Health Care":

```
<div class="knowurrights" style="max-width:676.6px; display:table;">
  <div class="knowurrights" style="vertical-align:top; border:0; float:left; display:table-cell;">
    <div class="knowurrights" style="vertical-align:top; border:0;">
      <a class="knowurrights" href="http://pegasuslaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/05c-MentalHealthCare.jpg">
      <img class="knowurrights" src="http://pegasuslaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/05c-MentalHealthCare.jpg" alt="05-MentalHealthCare" title="Therapy / Counseling 
Mental health care includes treatments such as individual therapy, group therapy, case management, behavior management, family therapy, substance abuse treatment, and other forms of verbal therapy that do not cause discomfort." style="display:block;" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="knowurrights" style="vertical-align:top; border:0;">
      <a class="knowurrights" href="http://pegasuslaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/05d-MentalHealthCare.jpg">
      <img class="knowurrights" src="http://pegasuslaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/05d-MentalHealthCare.jpg" alt="05-MentalHealthCare" title="Some Medications
When you are 14 years old or older, you can consent to psychotropic medication such as Ritalin, anti-depressants, anti-anxiety medication, and anti-psychotic medication.  However, your mental health care provider must tell your parents that you are taking this type of medication." style="display:block;" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="knowurrights" style="vertical-align:top; border:0;">
      <a class="knowurrights" href="http://pegasuslaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/05e-MentalHealthCare.jpg">
      <img class="knowurrights" src="http://pegasuslaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/05e-MentalHealthCare.jpg" alt="05-MentalHealthCare" title="Alcohol and drug use support 
When you are 14 years old or older, you can consent to alcohol and substance abuse treatment." style="display:block;" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="knowurrights" style="vertical-align:top; border:0; display:table-cell;">
    <a class="knowurrights" href="http://pegasuslaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/05b-MentalHealthCare.jpg">
    <img class="knowurrights" src="http://pegasuslaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/05b-MentalHealthCare.jpg" alt="05-MentalHealthCare" title="Mental Health Care 
When you are 14 years old or older, you can consent to mental health care on your own." style="display:block;" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Style.css for "knowurrights":

```
#knowurrights {
    font-size: 0;
    border: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    cell-padding: 0 !important;
    cell-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: top;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks much!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an easy fix, just add `table-layout:fixed` and `width: 100%;` to the div having `display:table`, and then remove the properties `display:table-cell` and `float:left` from its first(left) child div.